# JavaScript Date Undefined/NaN in IE8

Tags: javascript, date

I use this to test whether date inputs were less than 7 days from today's date it works in all browsers except < IE9

```
var today = new Date("<?=date("Y-m-d")?>"); //eg: 02-10-2012
var arrDate = new Date(startYear+"-"+startMonth+"-"+startDay); //eg: 05-10-2012
var diff = new Date(arrDate - today);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
if(days<7) alert("less than 7 days.");
```

I don't get an error in the IE console (F12) but `days` debugs as `NaN`, does anybody know what the problem is with IE?

Comment: Just as a note, try to avoid using PHP's short tags.

Comment: I tried your code (removing the php and variable concatenations replacing with shown data string) and guess what. Firefox gives an invalid Date object. The Date object has a constructor that requires Date(year, month, day, [etc]. I also note that you are using division against the Date object diff... does javascript provide operator overloading on Date?

Answer (score 15):

IE 8 (and below) do not recognize date strings in the `y-m-d` format.

I recommend you use `y/m/d`, as this is recognized by all browsers.

---

PS: Your comment is wrong.

```
new Date("<?=date("Y-m-d")?>"); //eg: 02-10-2012
```

should read

```
new Date("<?=date("Y-m-d")?>"); //eg: 2012-10-02
```

On a general note, you should never comment the obvious to avoid comments that do not reflect the code. `date("Y-m-d")` is pretty obvious, it does not need a comment at all.