# Java script Date.parse not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-8

hi i am using java script to compare between  two dates using date.parse function

```
var pfrmdt = Date.parse(frmdt);
var ptodt = Date.parse(todt);

                   if(pfrmdt <= ptodt)
                     {
                        return true;
                     }
                     else {


                          focusCtrl.value="";
                          focusCtrl.focus();
                        }
```

and the date format is dd/mmm/yyyy its working properly in other browsers but not in IE8. when I alerts the value of pfrmdt and ptodt  its showing NAN in IE8.
any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript JSON Date parse in IE7/IE8 returns NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020658/javascript-json-date-parse-in-ie7-ie8-returns-nan)

Comment: I have already take reference from your suggested ans but its doesnt work for me

Comment: There are many other dups, one of these should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098963/javascript-datedatestring-returns-nan-on-specific-server-and-browser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758581/javascript-date-returning-nan-in-ie8, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319479/in-ie-8-dates-are-nan-nan-nan, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687165/javascript-date-undefined-nan-in-ie8

Comment: How does your date look like? What is `frmdt` and `todt` value?

Comment: frmdt is 01/Oct/2013 and  todt is 02/Oct/2013 both are string

Comment: Dunno... I don't have IE8 but try http://momentjs.com/, that should work crossbrowser

Comment: or tell me any other solution to compare two dates in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.parse()` is part of ECMAScript-5. Microsoft browser support is as follows:

- IE9 Mode, IE10 Mode, and IE11 Mode

**References**

- [[ECMA-262/5] Section 15.9.4.2, Date.parse (string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff960739)